# Ffprobe error on php exec

Tags: ffprobe

Ffprobe not found.
Php command: `exec('youtube-dl -4 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JP4kValjHmw --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 -o deneme.mp3');`

Same with shell_exec.

But no problem in user or root ssh.

Ffmpeg, youtube-dl, ffprobe, libav-tools installed.

ffprobe not found problem is in PHP exec/shell_exec only.

```
    ffprobe version git-2015-12-13-906c0b7 Copyright (c) 2007-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)
  configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/root/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/usr/local/bin --pkg-config-flags=--static --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265
  libavutil      55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
  libavcodec     57. 17.100 / 57. 17.100
  libavformat    57. 20.100 / 57. 20.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 21.100 /  6. 21.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Simple multimedia streams analyzer
usage: ffprobe [OPTIONS] [INPUT_FILE]

You have to specify one input file.
Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffprobe'.
```

Comment: Full Error: "ERROR: ffprobe or avprobe not found. Please install one."